# How to change a private field in a parent class

Tags: java, reflection, private

I have using the Vaadin framework and want to override some behavior.

Problem is that all setters for a field have side effects that I don't want to invoke.

For this reason I want to set the private field directly.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void setItemDataSource(Item itemDataSource) {
    //do some stuff
    java.lang.reflect.Field privateField = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(itemDatasource); //Yes the spelling is correct.
    privateField.set(this, itemDataSource);   <<-- I get an error.
    //do more stuff
```

I get the following error.

> //TODO: copy paste error.

Apparently I'm not supposed to include `this` as the object who's field need to be changed, but some other reference.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the full exception trace? I assume even though you have to, you didn't set the visibility modifier for the private field to allow this. However, I must say, I don't encourage doing anything like this... (Aw. Assylias beat me by a margin :) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [make it accessible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) first:

```
privateField.setAccessible(true);
privateField.set(this, itemDataSource);
```